# How do I send a user a temporary, expiring URL using ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I have a Ruby/Rails app with a class, Engagements, and an ActionMailer mailer that sends out mail each time an Engagement is created. I want to include a link in that email that goes to a page on my site that creates and displays an item for the user. I want the link to expire after one click and I want the real URL (website.com/items/itemid, for example) that it's going to not to be shown. How can I achieve this? Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

you could add two fields to your model: token and has_expired (default: false) to your model.

ActionMailer would send the link with the generated token, once the user click the link and the token is validated, set has_expired to true.

If user tries to go again, expired is true so don't show the page ... i guess same thing would happen if user tried to go with invalid token.